# Only One Accordion Panel Open At A Time

Tags: jquery, accordion

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var allPanels = $('.accordian li div');
 

 allPanels.hide();
 $('#nav-list li a').click(function() {
  var id;
  
  if(this.id == id) {
   allPanels.slideUp('slow');
   alert("hello");
  }
  else {
   allPanels.slideUp('slow');
   $(this).parent('li').find('div').toggle('slow');
   id = this.id;
  }

  return false;

 });
});
```

```css
.accordian  {
 
 width: 300px;
 height: 400px;
}

.accordian li {
 width: 100%;
 list-style-type: none;
 padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 0; 

}
.accordian li:last-child {
 border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
.accordian a {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 color: black;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-weight: bold;
 background-color: #a3a3a3;
}
.contentArea {
 border-top: 0; 
    font-size: 12px;
    background-color: #7BBF6A;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="nav-list" class="accordian">
  <li id="select_1">
   <a href="">Some Text</a>
   <div class="contentArea">
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
   </div>
  </li>
  <li id="talk_1">
   <a href="">Some Text</a>
   <div class="contentArea">
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
   </div>
  <li id="talk_2">
   <a href="">Some Text</a>
   <div class="contentArea">
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
   </div>
  </li>
  <li id="talk_3">
   <a href="">Some Text</a>
   <div class="contentArea">
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
   </div>
  </li>
  <li id="talk_8">
   <a href="">Some Text</a>
   <div class="contentArea">
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
   </div>
  </li>
  <li id="talk_9">
   <a href="">Some Text</a>
   <div class="contentArea">
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
   </div>
  </li>
 </ul>
```

Have this simple accordion and would like to only have one accordion panel open at a time. My code works until I click on the same panel twice trying to close it. It won't close and it always has one panel open. Can anyone point out where I went wrong with my logic and how to fix it? I've included a code snippet:

Answer (score 1):

OK, another try with a different/simple way to do an accordian with JQuery.

First, the basic HTML.  There are two classes used .. no real css, just used class names as selectors.  There are .selector div's and .text divs.  You can see this in action at http://www.infohio.org/sample.

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <div id="select1" class="selector">Select 1</div>
    <div id="text1" class="text" style="display: none;">Text Goes Here</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div id="select2" class="selector">Select 2</div>
    <div id="text2" class="text" style="display: none;">Text Goes Here</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div id="select3" class="selector">Select 3</div>
    <div id="text3" class="text" style="display: none;">Text Goes Here</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div id="select4" class="selector">Select 4</div>
    <div id="text4" class="text" style="display: none;">Text Goes Here</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And the JQuery:

```
jQuery(function($) {
   $(".selector").on("click",function() {
      var id=$(this).attr("id").replace("select","");
      $(".text").hide();
      $("#text"+id).show(500);
   });
});
```

When the selector is clicked, it uses the selector ID to get the associated text ID.  Then all the .text div's are hidden and the selected .text div is shown.

Comment: Thank you. However when I used the code you provided it didn't work. It's probably due to my html structure so I included a code snippet so you can see exactly what I see. It looks like the first part of my if statement is never true.

Answer (score 1):

1. The problem why your `alert section` is never true because, you have
   set the `var id;` as a **local variable**. Because of that value is
   never stored , and it always remains undefined whenever click
   function is executed, Hence make it **global variable.**
2. There is another problem, you have written `click` event for
       **anchor tag** `$('#nav-list li a').click(function() {...}`, hence `this.id` will try retreive id of anchor and not of `li`,
   hence u
       need to change the id to anchor tag.

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var allPanels = $('.accordian li div');

    var id;
    allPanels.hide();
    $('#nav-list li a').click(function() {          
        if(this.id == id) {
            allPanels.slideUp('slow');
            alert("hello");
        }
        else {
            allPanels.slideUp('slow');
            $(this).parent('li').find('div').toggle('slow');
            id = this.id;
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Or you could make the `var id;`global and get the `id` of the **parent** i.e `li` instead of moving the id to anchor tag.

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/kss92obp/)**

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var allPanels = $('.accordian li div');

var id;
    allPanels.hide();
    $('#nav-list li a').click(function() {  
        if($(this).closest('li').attr('id') == id) {
            $(this).parent('li').find('div').toggle('slow');            
        }
        else {
            allPanels.slideUp('slow');
            $(this).parent('li').find('div').toggle('slow');
            id = $(this).closest('li').attr('id');
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I would like to retrieve the value of the li and evaluate that in my `if` statement. would i do something like `$(this).parent('li').id`?

Comment: `$(this).parent('li').attr('id')` or `$(this).closest('li').attr('id')`

Comment: @webDev: I have edited my answer , using closest to find the id of the li and i have provided a demo as well. Hope it helps.